# Is ".net" a valid tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

Seems to me it's a bit unecessary because the other tags on questions tagged with it indicate that the area of Tridion being discussed is .NET

What does everyone else think?

https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/.net

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Neither of those questions seem to be about .net. I removed the tag from those questions.

Comment: On those two questions it looks like people are using the .net tag just to indicate they are coding in .net (as opposed to java I guess) and not to ask specific questions about .net so I say removing them was definitely the way to go.

Answer (score 2):

I would not recommend using .NET tag, I think SDL Tridion specific tags are sufficient, as all of us know what all parts of SDL Tridion are in .NET (C# TBB, Event System etc.) and what all are in Java (Deployer Extn, Storage Ext. or Pre-Processors etc.)

Apart from it; it would be related to configuration/installation or some other common things like Component Presentation in Java or .NET, so it would be better if specify that in the question as well instead of having a separate tag altogether.
Thoughts?